# My model doesn't set up for texture painting properly

Tags: objects, 3d-view, texture-painting

Hi I am following [Darin Lyles texture painting vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hr_itixx0Yo)

When I paint my character, only some of it goes black, the rest is bright orange. I am not sure what I have done wrong.
[image: model in texture paint mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do that:

1. List item
2. Select your object
3. Go to Edit mode ( <kbd>Tab</kbd> key)
4. Go to *UV Editing* ( see bottom of the application)
5. Move the mouse under your object, press <kbd>U</kbd> key, and select *Smart UV Project*.
   You can use Mark Seam / Mark Sharp ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) to fix your UV map.

This will make your texture based on the UV map.
This texture is your cloth material (with UV).

When you are painting your texture you will paint on this texture.

Comment: cheers I think I did it like that, is fixed anyway

Comment: @Duarte:Thank's for edit with tags. I don't know about that keyboard markdown.

Comment: @Dave: if you fix your issue then follow the rules of stackexchange to check proper answer or you can put your answer here.

Comment: @DaveGoateze f this answer solved your problem please consider marking it as correct, or if it helped you at least upvote it

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: @Ramons I'm not very good with english language also I have a fast replay. I read your edit answer and good to know about how to deal with: https://www.blender.org/manual/en/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/overview.html !